# Entity Framework Single Result ObjectResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure which always returns a single row
Currently my code looks something like this

```
public void DoSomthing()
{
    ObjectResult<pDoesProductExist_Result> pDoesProductExistResults = tbsDBEntities.pDoesProductExist(itemCode);
                foreach (pDoesProductExist_Result pDoesProductExistResult in pDoesProductExistResults)
                {
                   return;
                }
...
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pDoesProductExist_Result exists = tbsDBEntities.pDoesProductExist(itemCode).Single();
```